# Expected value of $100$th item in series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, expected-value

> A sequence is defined in the following way: $x_0 = 0$, and:
>
> $
>   x_{n+1} =
>   \begin{cases}
>                                    x_n + A_n & \text{if $A_n | x_n$} \\
>                                    x_n - A_n & \text{otherwise}
>   \end{cases}
> $

where $A_n$ is an integer chosen at random with uniform probability from $\{1,2,...,10\}$. What is the expected value of $x_{100}$?

I cannot see how I can calculate this if I dont know the probability that $A_n$ divides $x_n$?

I can see that $\mathbb{E}[x_1] = 5.5$ but I cannot see how to find the expected value of the sum.

Comment: hints or full soloution ?

Comment: anything, i dont know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_n$ was just a randomly chosen integer and $A_n$ fixed then the probability $A_n$ divides $x_n$ is simply $\frac{1}{A_n}$

Hence: $\mathbb{E}[x_{n+1} - x_n | A_n] = \frac{1}{A_n} \cdot (A_n) + (1-\frac{1}{A_n}) \cdot(-A_n) = -A_n +2$

So by tower property $\mathbb{E}[x_{n+1} - x_n ] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[x_{n+1} - x_n | A_n]] = \mathbb{E}[-A_n +2] = -5.5+2 = -3.5$

This is true for all $n \not=1$ as $0$ is divisible by all numbers. As you pointed out $\mathbb{E}[x_1] = 5.5$

Hence $\mathbb{E}[x_{100}] = 5.5 + 99(-3.5) = -341$

Comment: " then the probability $A_n$ divides $x_n$ is simply $\frac{1}{A_n}$
" can you justify this?

Comment: pick a random integer. what is the probability it is even? half right. what about the probability its a multiple of 3? 1/3 yes. what about a multiple of 1569 ? $\frac{1}{1569}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4274899/expected-number-of-rolls-until-all-consecutive-differences-have-been-seen could you take a look at this one?

Comment: Problem is $x_n$ cannot be assumed completely random, exact value is more close to $-341.4788182$, but it is a good guess

Answer (score 2):

Here is more of an algorithmic approach which shows the correct value is $\approx -341.4788182$, or exactly if you want:

> -1707394090963579349817072377461921154262130526073984320234251558493902918430631569027263581342163035599/5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I've used an algorithm executed in Python based on the following observation: $x_n=X$ if and only if $x_{n-1}=X-i$, $A_{n-1}=i$ and $i \mid X$ OR $x_{n-1}=X+i, A_{n-1}=i$,$i\nmid X$ (for some $i \in \{1,2,\dots,10\}$. This follows directly from the problem statement, only simplification is replacing $i\mid X - i$ (resp. $i \nmid X+i$) with equivalent $i \mid X$ (resp. $i \nmid X$). So we store probabilities $P(x_{n-1}=X)$ and use the recursive relation above to calculate $P(x_{n}=X)$. We always only need to store only the previous probabilities.

In the algorithm implementation itself, I've just gone through all the values and probabilities for $x_{n-1}$ and iterated over values of $A=1,2,\dots 10$ to generate values and probabilities for $x_n$. Here is a quick implementation in Python 3:

```
import fractions

probs_last = {0:fractions.Fraction(1)}
n = 0

while n < 100:
    n += 1
    probs_n = {}

    for x, p in probs_last.items():
        for A in range(1, 10+1):
            x_n = x + A if (x % A == 0) else x - A
            if x_n not in probs_n:
                probs_n[x_n] = 0
            probs_n[x_n] += p / 10

    probs_last = probs_n

E = 0
for val, p in probs_last.items():
    E += p*val

print(n, float(E), E)
```

which outputs the approximate value $-341.4788181927159$ as well as the exact fraction. I've tried also multiple Monte Carlo simulations and it seems somehow around the value (or at least closer to it than to $-341$):

```
100000: -341.52394
200000: -341.48729
300000: -341.43399
400000: -341.3589725
500000: -341.346456
600000: -341.3863083333333
...
```

I suspect that the value $-341$ in the other answer is a bit off because the $x_n$ cannot be just assumed to be completely random.

That being said, I don't know how to arrive at this exact value with more "pencil & paper" method, maybe someone will find a way in another answer.

Comment: nice stuff, you are right about my answer actually . glad we both get similar results tho!

Comment: I've got from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275429) that all these recent questions from Trajan are from a quantitative finance interview prepper. $-341$ is the estimate provided in that prepper.